# Bash: How refresh shell after installing virtualenvwrapper [Without restarting the shell]?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, fabric, apt-get

I am using `python-fabric` to setup my server, which configures the server programatically.

So, I installed `virtualenvwrapper` as :

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper
```

That installed - Virtualenvwrapper and adds its initialization scripts to shell startup.

Generally we restart the shell and it gets initialized, but in my case I can-not restart the shell over `fabric`.

Since it was installed with `apt-get` I was not able to find the initialization scripts entry in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`

So, where did `apt-get` added call to the initialization scripts ?

How to refresh the `shell` without restarting the shell ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved the problem :

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

This is where it was storing all its magic which gets included to `.bashrc` automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try `hash -r`. It is a bash builtin.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

But I'm not sure the path of virtualenvwrapper.sh installed from apt-get. (I usually use easy_install)

Answer (score 1):

Try `rehash`. (http://www.computerhope.com/unix/urehash.htm)

Comment: It says : The rehash command re-computes the internal hash table of the contents of directories listed in the path environmental variable to account for new commands added.

Can you ellaborate what does it actually does ? I am not able to understand its statement.

Comment: Also, its not available in ubuntu by default.

Comment: It parse your all folders in `PATH` variable and for each of them, search all executable file, when it spot one, add it to internal hashmap (i.e.: when you type `ls`, it will be mapped for full path to executable file, like: `/etc/bin/ls`)

Comment: Ok seems workable but can we do it in a simpler way without needing install another package ?

Comment: Well, I don't think so. Hash table is keeping in memory, so to dig into it, you should probably use linux API and... write your own `rehash` program :)

Comment: :( But, I can't do either. I googled and found that `source ~/.bashrc`, but that didn't helped may be because it was not sourced from that file. Can we do it some fashion like that ?

Comment: You could always run it by finding direct location ie ``./etc/bin/ls``